# How to solve keychain access warning after app transfer to new account

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have few question about "Potential Loss of Keychain Access ".

I transfer one app from old account to new account but now i want to update that application and when i try submit update build xcode show me warrning Potential Loss of Keychain Access but no error (using new provisioning profile by xcode).
So i search on google about it and i found that its because old Team id and new Team id , its differnt and because of that you can not have provisioning profile containing old team id.
So i create new provisioning profile using XCode  something like "xc:com.TESTING.Test" and submitted app by using that with warrining.

but after submitting app i receive an email from apple saying "The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['XYZXYZ.com.TESTING.Test'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['ABCABC.com.TESTING.Test']. This will result in a loss of keychain access."

So my questions are as follows :-

1) If i use new provisioning profile ignoring "keychain access warrning" then my app will not able to access NSUSerDefaults? or any other important information? (and this problem occures with only old install or new install also dont have access to keychain?)

2) How to solve this problem?

Any help is appriciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs - [Resolving the Potential Loss of Keychain Access warning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1726/_index.html), [A one-time loss in keychain data will occur if you switch your App ID prefix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014135-CH1-A_ONE_TIME_LOSS_IN_KEYCHAIN_DATA_WILL_OCCUR_IF_YOU_SWITCH_YOUR_APP_ID_PREFIX) -, **this will happen anyway**.

**`NSUserDefaults`** has nothing to do with this. If you have not used Keychain Services - [Keychain Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/) -, you can safely omit this warning as they say.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact with Apple customer service, they will change your TeamID to new account instead of keeping using old TeamID. Then creating new provisioning profile and connect to your app which has just been transfered.

Comment: So it is possible to transfer an App and continue using the keychain without a loss?